# What's the best way to exclude a node in an svg file when using xsl-fo to generate a pdf?

Tags: xml, pdf, svg, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have some SVG files that I'd like to create a PDF with.  For simplicity lets assume each one represents one page in the PDF. There is a node in the SVG containing some text that I would like to exclude.  How do I go about doing so?  Here's a sample SVG file and fo to include it as a page in the PDF.

Lets say there exists a file named /home/dave/images/some_image.svg containing this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="470" height="363" xml:space="preserve">
  <g clip-path="url(#some-path)">
    <rect id="some-rect" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#666" height="363" width="470" opacity="1" x="0" y="0"/>
    <defs id="some-defs">
      <clipPath id="some-path" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect height="363" x="0" y="0" width="470" fill="#fff"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id="some-group">
      <path id="a-path"/>
      <g id="a-container">
        <text id="some-text" x="235" y="181">This text needs to go</text>
        <image x="-2000" y="-1500" width="4000" height="3000" xlink:href="http://www.somewebsite.com/image.jpg" id="some-img"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and now for a sample fo that uses it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" margin="0pt"
                           page-height="363pt" page-width="470pt">
      <fo:region-body />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic 
            src='/home/dave/images/some_image.svg'/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
```

So this works fine for including the whole svg "as is".  How can I exclude the text node?

```
<text id="some-text" x="235" y="181">This text needs to go</text>
```

As for the real files I'm using they reference a font that I won't need to include in the PDF and the text will be behind the image anyway thus not viewable.

Comment: How are you creating the XSL-FO?

Comment: Just manually for now.  I'll have to generate either the xsl-fo or xslt programmatically later on somehow - probably with python and lxml. So while doing that I could process the svg files and strip out the unwanted node(s) but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant, declarative solution using xsl.

Comment: I'm no FO guru but I would go for stripping the undesired node in an XSLT step. Svg is after all a form of xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keeping `<fo:external-graphic />` : XSLT pre-processing

If you want or need to keep the `<fo:external-graphic />` approach, then you should certainly pre-process your SVG using XSLT, as suggested by [Wivani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701884/wivani)

A copy-all template and a remove template should be enough, like:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text[@id='some-text']"/>
```

You can keep your FO as-is, maybe changing the SVG path to the new, pre-processed SVG:

```
<fo:external-graphic src='/home/dave/images/some_image_stripped.svg'/>
```

For more specific info, see other SO questions like:

- [XSLT 1.0: copy everything except certain nodes according to value and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078881/xslt-1-0-copy-everything-except-certain-nodes-according-to-value-and-variable)
- [XSL: how to copy a tree, but removing some nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137563/xsl-how-to-copy-a-tree-but-removing-some-nodes)
- [How to copy everything as is and only remove a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364409/how-to-copy-everything-as-is-and-only-remove-a-specific-element)

### Alternative using `<fo:instream-foreign-object />`

If, on the other hand, you want to keep a one-step process, you can investigate at inlining you SVG in your XML-FO, using `<fo:instream-foreign-object />`.

But this would likely require you to change your processing logic, creating the XML-FO by means of an XSL transformation *from* your SVG file. This could conflict with other requirements of yours.

You can have a look at [Displaying SVG using XSLFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340476/displaying-svg-using-xslfo) for more info on this technique.